# An adjective to describe posessing pride / self importance, but not with a connotation of exaggeration

Tags: single-word-requests

Single word request.

Starting with a few words such as "arrogant", "cocky", or "pretentious", these words typically imply a certain level of exaggeration, used in situations where someone is not as good as they think they are.

If John thinks he is far stronger and superior than what he actually is, and constantly makes it known, one may call him one of the above words.

Suppose you have a similar scenario with Bill, who also constantly makes it known he is stronger and superior, but, this is, in fact, *actually the case.*

What adjective would you use to describe Bill?

Answer (score 1):

Bill is **self-assured**.

> Full of or characterized by self-assurance; self-confident.

[OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/58938345?redirectedFrom=self-assured#eid)

> having or showing confidence in yourself and your abilities

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-assured)

> The self-assured young royal reportedly took charge of the royal wedding party on Saturday

[Town&Country - Re: Princess Charlotte - 23 May 2018](https://www.townandcountrymag.com/society/tradition/a20886637/princess-charlotte-royal-wedding-bossy/)

Answer (score 1):

**ostentatious** ( [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ostentatious)

> adj.
>   1. characterized by pretentious show in an attempt to impress others.
>   2. intended to attract notice: ostentatious charity. [1650–60]

Answer (score 1):

[**Vainglorious**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vainglorious):

> marked by vainglory : BOASTFUL
>
> having or showing too much pride in your abilities or achievements
>
> a *vainglorious* woman who always insists on being the center of attention

The qualification that this person "constantly makes it known" acts as a negative trait, not *just* as a statement of fact.

Comment: Good  call.  "Vainglorious" fits the bill.

Answer (score 0):

"Constantly makes it known he is stronger and superior"? A **show-off**, or an **exhibitionist**, I would call him. **Not adjectives but often used attributively.**

> If you say that someone is a show-off, you are criticizing them for trying to impress people by showing in a very obvious way what they can do or what they own. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/show-off)

Comment: Those are nouns; an adjective was requested.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose you have a similar scenario with Bill, who also constantly makes it known he is stronger and superior, but, this is, in fact, actually the case.

You use *pride* in the title **"An adjective to describe possessing pride / self importance"**

As an adjective you might just use **proud**.

This works fine when attached to a title that designates what they're proud of to some degree:

- "Joe bob, the proud champion of this year's weight lifting event"  works without the "of"

My only reservation is that "he is a proud man"  has a certain idiomatic meaning to it that is more about "respect" and "dignity" and a "unwillingness to receive aid"  .

But, as soon as you use **proud of** I think you get what you are looking for.

While "proud of himself" works generally ...  depending on it's context it can sound overdone as in "cocky" in a snarky way.. generally to get that sarcasm you'd need a "very proud of " and some inflection.

- Certainly calling a boy "proud of himself for his painting ability" is not a cut without more hits.

Answer (score -1):

A person may be arrogant or cocky (or **vain**) about a superiority that they do truly have. Those words imply unattractive excessive pride, which may or may not be misplaced. They do not automatically imply an exaggerated opinion of one's own worth, although, of course, vanity is a character flaw.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vain

Comment: My concern is with the dictionary's definition, saying vain describes someone who is "*too* interested" (emphasis mine) in themselves. Doesn't this imply that they are more interested in themselves than they should be, ergo, they do not have the qualities they think they do?

Comment: A person can be "too interested" in a superiority that they actually possess. Many people who are physically attractive are only too aware of being so.

Comment: "Too" may imply "more than cultural standards". If "interested" is interpreted along that spectrum, then whether or not one actually has the qualities in question is independent of that "too".